# Production Server export csv file with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, server

I have a question regarding file export on a production server. I have two server instance hosted in AWS. , one is development and one is production. I am trying to export a list of participants in the database.I am using ruby on rails with postgresql. The way I implemented it is to write the records into a csv file. I am able to export the list in development environment. However, on the production server, I have never been able to export the list. 
This is a real headache and I could not think of any solutions because I do not know what might have caused this issue.

The error I got when export is

```
/tmp/mozilla_XXXXXX/2DUwsUXD.xls.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
```

Here I replaced sensitive data with XXXXX.

Does not one know what might be the cause? could it be a server timeout issue?